# How to do a count(*) in Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, count

How can I count the records in a MySQL table in Hibernate? I tried the following HQL, but it does not work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEMBERS WHERE `username` =:USERNAME OR  `email` =:EMAIL
```

It is used in the following method:

```
public boolean checkInfos() {
    Session newSession = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    int count = (Integer) newSession.createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEMBERS WHERE  `username` ='admin' OR  `email` ='admin'").uniqueResult();

    if (count >= 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need that

```
Query q = newSession.createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEMBERS WHERE  username = ? OR  email =?");
q.setParameter( 1, "your username");
q.setParameter(2, "your email");
```

Comment: @Kaan: Please give errors a bit more love. They contain namely the answer to your problem. You should not ignore errors as if they are garbage. If you do not understand what errors are trying to tell you, then you should edit your question and include them, so that we can explain them for you in layman's terms.

Answer (score 0):

`Select count(*)` returns a `Long`, not an `Integer`.

One more thing: The backticks, which you are using, are not accepted by every database.

By the way, you can use count(*) also in HQL. This means, you can use createQuery instead of createSQLQuery. An advantage of HQL is, it is portable from one database to another, which is not always the case for SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You also can achieve this by using criteria also.

```
private Number getCount(){
   Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Members.class);
   criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("username", "admin"), Restrictions.eq("email","admin")));
   criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
   return (Number) criteria.list();
}
```